# Как исправить разное отображение шрифтов в CSS?

Tags: google-chrome, html, firefox, css, шрифты

В Mozilla Firefox и Google-chrome по разному отображается размер текста. Как это можно корректировать в css?

Пример: критично в правом блоке и в блоке с текстом "Осуществление непосредственной власти народа РФ."
http://srv36748.ht-test.ru/

Comment: опишите более подробную причину - у меня все кооректно отображаеться

Comment: Проверьте для начала масштаб отображения в разных браузерах по умолчанию. Может, причина вовсе и не в стилях...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используем файл reset.css и всё будет ОК